# traceback with spotipy's util.prompt

Tags: python, spotipy

I've been working with the spotipy python API for a few days, trying to get it to work. Each time I try for a login request, it tracebacks with bad oauth request.

I've used this code:

```
id='my_client_id'

secret='my_client_secret'

url='https://mywebsite.mydomain/callback'
username='myusername'
scope='a list of scopes'
token=util.prompt(username, scope, client_id=id, client_secret=secret, url)
```

I then paste in a url that looks like:

```
https://mywebsite.mydomain/callback?code=a_long_code
```

But each time it gives me a bad request from oauth. Am I missing something? It seems to go through the login process fine, it's just it tracebacks at the end.

Comment: Have you checked [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues?q=bad+request)? Maybe there is something helpful there.

Comment: Multiple times. I also run some more tests, instead of using util, I ran each step by hand, it tracebacks, obviously, at the get_access_token(code) part. but it does have the code correct, and sp_oauth.redirect_uri is also set correctly... Is there something I should have set with spotify that would be raising a bad request error?

Comment: Just checked, and the URL's are in the spotify whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case people have this issue in the future, here is what I did:

1. In oauth2.py, find where it raises the error, and before that put something like: self.problem=response.
2. Run the steps that util.prompt does by hand, I.E, do the oauth_url requests yourself, rather than through util.prompt.
3. See what sp_oauth.problem.text says.

In my case, it was an incorrect app secret.
MORTIFIED!